# How to keep track of number of objects created in java

Tags: java, object, count

As Java does has an automatic garbage collector, it does not have a destructor. How will I come to know that an object has garbage so to decrement the static variable count?

Comment: Why do you care? Once your object is no longer reference by anything, it will be eligable for garbage collection, and will eventually be gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects have finalize() method which is called by the garbage collector when it determines that there are no more references to the object.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--)

Comment: Can I overload finalize()?

Comment: You can override it, but not overload.